# Gradle add 2 source files from directory

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project that by default adds `src\main\java`.

I need to add 2 additional files that are outside of this directory - say `../project1/src/main/java/com/github/blabla/pcg1/`

if I do it like this:
`sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += '../project1/src/main/java/com/github/blabla/pcg1/'`

I see they appear in the log

```
File in source set: C:\...\src\main\java
File in source set: C:\.../project1/src/main/java/com/github/blabla/pcg1/
```

But then they do not compile - the files in `/project1/src/main/java/com/github/blabla/pcg1/` relate each other and the compilation fails because they cannot find each other.

My suspicion is that they are located in a wrong directory, so to say.

if I would do
`sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += '../project1/src/main/java/'`

Then all the files in another project will be compiled - which I don't want.

I've also tried to include only those 2 files, but I can't find any working example how to add all files int one source dir and only specific files in another.

I.e.
I would expect something like this to work

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src"
            srcDir "../project1/src/main/java/com/github/blabla/pcg1/" {
                include 'fil1.java'
                include 'fil2.java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it does not.

Or i've tried

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            srcDir '../project1/src/main/java/'
            includes[
                    'com/github/blabla/pcg1/fil1.java',
                    'com/github/blabla/pcg1/fil2java'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to properly add specific 2 files from another project to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

- You don't need to "re-include" the normal project Java source, so no need for lines like:

```
srcDir 'src'
```

- The `includes` and `excludes` methods can be called with a Groovy `Closure`, which is similar to a lambda (see [API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html) for `PatternFilterable`, an interface which is implemented by `SourceDirectorySet`).

  The `Closure` will be called with each [`FileTreeElement`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTreeElement.html) in the `SourceDirectorySet` and you return a `Boolean` to stipulate whether each element is to be included or excluded.

So to include only your specific files in the directory and keep all the regular source included, you can write something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            def extraDir = "../project1/src/main/java/com/github/blabla/pcg1"
            srcDir extraDir
            include { fileElement ->
                fileElement.file.parentFile != file(extraDir) ||
                    fileElement.file == file("$extraDir/Foo.java") ||
                    fileElement.file == file("$extraDir/Bar.java")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will include the files `Foo.java` and `Bar.java` in your extra directory, but exclude everything else.